# Can't change ownership of '/dev/gpiomem' in a docker container in RPi

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, chown

I'm trying to run a simple docker container with a python base image to control the LEDs on my RPi4.

The Dockerfile compiles fine and I'm running it as follows:
`docker run --rm -ti --privileged --device /dev/gpiomem:/dev/gpiomem -d led_blinker bash`

Once inside the docker container I run a `ls -l /dev/gpiomem` and I get

```
root@ca1506d00cc5:/# ls -l /dev/gpiomem
crw-rw---- 1 nobody nogroup 246, 0 Dec 30 21:47 /dev/gpiomem
```

I try to do

```
root@ca1506d00cc5:/# chown root.root /dev/gpiomem
chown: changing ownership of 'dev/gpiomem': Operation not permitted
```

But when I run a `whoami` I get I'm the root user. What is that I'm missing?

PS. I have also added the flag `--user root` and got the same results.

Comment: Isn't that kind of question supposed to be asked in [raspberry pi StackExchange?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com), also you might want to check [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60240/what-sets-ownership-and-privileges-on-dev-gpiomem).

Comment: Thanks, I'll post there too. The post you linked uses the bare metal Pi, which it works fine on my end. I think my main issue is that somehow Docker doesn't allow me to do that